# why jquery time picker selects minutes by default

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, datetimepicker, timepicker

I am using jQuery time picker .When I select hour be default it add minutes  to it then I have to select my desire minutes always to change it.But my question is when I select hour it should not select minutes by default.How it is possible or is anything is possible that when I select hour from time picker by default minutes should be 00.Next I can change minutes on my choice.

Comment: could you please paste the url of plugin which you are using

Comment: I am using this time picker http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/